# Use a Cached Version of MySQL Results when Loading Laravel View

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a `Laravel` view with a lot of data analysis results. All of these values are being calculated in a `Mysql` view as single field results before being loaded as variables in its `Laravel` route.

eg.

```
userCount | veryActiveUserCount | veryActiveUserMalePercent
-----------------------------------------------------------
88292     | 43223               | 59
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

The problem is this `MySQL` query takes about 10 seconds which causes Laravel to timeout.

This query only needs to be run once per day so getting fresh data for each pageload isn't required. Is there a way to use a cached version of my results when I load the `Laravel` view?

Comment: Show your code and point what you need to be cached at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read the [docs about caching](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/cache)?

You can cache a query like this:

```
$value = Cache::get('key', function () {
    return DB::table(...)->get();
});
```

In your case you should "warm" the cache once/twice a day so no user has to wait if the cache expires. You can do this in an artisan command with a [scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling).